# Can you animate a font awesome icon?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I have a webpage with a paper airplane [icon](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/paper-plane/) from font awesome. Is it possible, since it is a font, to make it have a small animation? 
For example, make it shrink and fly away and the appear from under?
With jQuery, javascript or CSS?

[image: plane]

Comment: You can animate the containing element as you would any other. IIRC for font awesome it's an `i` element.

Comment: Yes. Either CSS animation or JS can be used - but I would recommend just using CSS to animate scale and position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### JQuery Animation

Here's an example using JQuery and CSS. I'm using a rocket icon () because the plane icon doesn't display reliably on my computer (✈️ ← all I can see is a rectangular box).

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#plane-icon").click(function(){
        $(this).animate({
            left:'180px',
            top:'-20px',
            fontSize:'20px'
          },2000);
        $(this).animate({
            left:'0px',
            top:'180px',
            fontSize:'100px'
          },0);
        $(this).animate({
            left:'0px',
            top:'80px',
          },1000);
    });
});
```

```css
.icon-wrap {
  width:180px;
  height:180px;
  font-size:100px;
  cursor:pointer;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}

#plane-icon {
  position:absolute;
  top:80px;
  left:0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="icon-wrap">
  <span id="plane-icon"></span>
</div>
```

---

### CSS Animation

Here's the same animation done with CSS keyframe animation instead of JQuery's `animate()` function. The `animationend` event trigger is used to reset the CSS class of the object after it has finished animating.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('body').on('webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend oAnimationEnd msAnimationEnd animationend',
    function(){
      $('#plane-icon').removeClass('launched');
    }
  );
  $('#plane-icon').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('launched');
  });
});
```

```css
.icon-wrap {
  width:180px;
  height:180px;
  font-size:100px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

#plane-icon {
  display:block;
  cursor:pointer;
  transform:translate(0px,80px) scale(1);
}

#plane-icon.launched {
  animation-name:rocket;
  animation-duration:3s;
  cursor:default;
}


@keyframes rocket {
  0% {
    transform:translate(0px,80px) scale(1);
  }
  66% {
    transform:translate(120px,-80px) scale(0.1);
  }
  67% {
    transform:translate(120px,180px) scale(0.1);
  }
  68% {
    transform:translate(0px,180px) scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    transform:translate(0px,80px) scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="icon-wrap">
  <span id="plane-icon"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Just be aware that this approach will incur a relayout and repaint in the browser (http://csstriggers.com) which can hurt the frame rate. My pure CSS solution below avoids this.

Comment: Agreed. Also using top and left properties instead of CSS transforms means that the browser cannot offload the effects to GPU if the needs call for it, and that the former only do pixel increments and doesn't support subpixel movements, which will appear jittery at slower animation durations.

Comment: @TedWhitehead Thanks, I was unaware of that. I'll see if I can re-jig this answer to use CSS animation instead.

Comment: how did you add the "hide/show code"?

Comment: @FlipFloop In the CSS animation? Between 66% and 68%, the rocket quickly moves down and to the left while scaling back to its original size. It's outside the visible area of the parent div while this is happening, so you don't see it.

Answer (score 7):

Sure! It doesn’t matter if it’s a font icon or an SVG icon, you can still animate the element with CSS.

Here’s an example animation:

```
@keyframes fly {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  25% {
    transform: scale(0.5);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(0.5) translate(100vw, -100vh);
  }
}

.plane {
  display: inline-block;
  fill: #e24145;// for demo purposes, only applies to SVGs

  &.is-active {
    animation-name: fly;
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
}
```

Working demo http://codepen.io/tedw/pen/PZXjYv

Comment: thx! this helped a bunch!

Comment: no prob, glad it was helpful!