# Does JavaScript need more processing power than CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, performance

I had a [a question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35326343/can-you-animate-a-font-awesome-icon/) and I got multiple answers to animate a font from font awesome (considered like normal text), the first was this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#plane-icon").click(function(){
        $(this).animate({
            left:'180px',
            top:'-20px',
            fontSize:'20px'
        },2000);
        $(this).animate({
            left:'0px',
            top:'180px',
            fontSize:'100px'
        },0);
        $(this).animate({
            left:'0px',
            top:'80px',
        },1000);
    });
});

.icon-wrap {
    width:180px;
    height:180px;
    font-size:100px;
    cursor:pointer;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#plane-icon {
    position:absolute;
    top:80px;
    left:0px;
}
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="icon-wrap">
    <span id="plane-icon"></span>
</div>
```

the second answer, with the same result, was this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').on('webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend oAnimationEnd msAnimationEnd animationend',
        function(){
            $('#plane-icon').removeClass('launched');
        }
    );
    $('#plane-icon').click(function(){
        $(this).addClass('launched');
    });
});
.icon-wrap {
    width:180px;
    height:180px;
    font-size:100px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#plane-icon {
    display:block;
    cursor:pointer;
    transform:translate(0px,80px) scale(1);
}

#plane-icon.launched {
    animation-name:rocket;
    animation-duration:3s;
    cursor:default;
}


@keyframes rocket {
    0% {
        transform:translate(0px,80px) scale(1);
    }
    66% {
        transform:translate(120px,-80px) scale(0.1);
    }
    67% {
        transform:translate(120px,180px) scale(0.1);
    }
    68% {
        transform:translate(0px,180px) scale(1);
     }
     100% {
         transform:translate(0px,80px) scale(1);
     }
}
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="icon-wrap">
    <span id="plane-icon"></span>
</div>
```

Which of these 2 will require less processing power?

Comment: You must use css when you can instead of javascript to make animations or other things that CSS can make natively. Although there are more factors

Comment: Easily the CSS solution. The animations can be hardware accelerated, which means it's mostly in the GPU's hands and you don't have to perform all of that extra object boxing done in the first example. You could speed up the first one by caching `$(this)` (`var $this = $(this)`) but the CSS one will probably still end up being faster. When in doubt: profile.

Comment: thx guys! love this site!

Comment: Check this too...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27094587/css-animations-vs-jquery-animations

Comment: Caching `$(this)` in this case would have practically zero effect performance-wise.